# Pass a parameter to another JavaScript and run the script

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, cheerio

Send a parameter(URL) from another script through recursion to this script.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var app     = express();

var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var murl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/getData';

url = '';

app.get('/getData', function(req, res){
    firstCall(req,res)
    //console.log("cookie",req.cookies);
})

var firstCall = function(req, res, data){
    console.log("URL: ", url);
    res.send('Check your console!');
}

app.listen('3000')
console.log('Magic happens on port 3000');
module.exports = function(app) {  
  app.get('/getData', function() {});
};
```

I want this code to act as backbone or logic board. And some other file should be able to trigger this logic board file by adding the URL to this file.

Like we pass parameters to function to call. How do I do it here.

Comment: Pass parameter to what?

Comment: I need this " url = ' ' "  to be filled dynamically

Comment: Pass it in on the command line?

Comment: no I can create another script that should call this script and add URL to this script

Comment: wrap all your current script into a function and call that function by passing a parameter.. that is what you want right?

Comment: Yes. But I was searching if there is a better way to make it as a module in my project